# How to convert data from type {} to type array [] in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, laravel

I am trying to display data from cart on page using react js the prodcts in cart are in this form

```
{"2":{"id":2,"name":"Special","price":17,"quantity":"2","attributes":[],"conditions":[]},"8":{"id":8,"name":"Mushroom","price":10,"quantity":"1","attributes":[],"conditions":[]}}
```

so if I type http:localhost:8000/cart I get this form above.

In my js file I tried to fetch the data like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import MyGlobleSetting from './MyGlobleSetting';


class CartChosen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={products:[] }
      this.handleSubmit3 = this.handleSubmit3.bind(this);
  }


componentDidMount() {

  axios.get('myCart') 
  .then(response => {

    this.setState({ products: response.data });

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}

  render() {
    return (


          <div>
      <div className="row">
        {this.state.products.map(data=>
         <div className="card" key= {data.id}>
             <div className="card-header"><h4>{data.title}</h4>
             <h4>{data.id}</h4>
             </div>
             <div className="card-body">


          </div>
          </div>
        )}
       </div>  

<div>

       <div>Total price in Euro:</div> 
    <div>Total price in Dollar:</div>

    <button className="btn btn-dark"><Link to="order-completed">Comlplete order</Link></button>

</form>      
    </div> 
    </div>
    );
  }
}


export default CartChosen;
```

So I realised that data from cart are in `{}` and I am trying to display this type `[]` with `.map` does anyone know how to convert from this type data `{}` to this type `[]` so I can show products?

This is error:

```
app.js:73857 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.products.map is not a function
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your data from an object to an array, if you were just to use the values from the object you can simply use

```
const keyValues = {"2":{"id":2,"name":"Special","price":17,"quantity":"2","attributes":[],"conditions":[]},"8":{"id":8,"name":"Mushroom","price":10,"quantity":"1","attributes":[],"conditions":[]}}
```

and convert it's values to an array

```
const valuesArray = Object.values(keyValues)
```